# Comparision of variable importance plots in the randomForest and gbm package

Tags: r, random-forest, gbm

i have a question concerning the comparision of variable importance plots in the randomForest and gbm package:

I am comparing a random forest and gbm classifier in the context of binary classification.

I implemented the rf with the randomForest package (by [Liaw](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) ) and the gbm with the gbm package (by [Greenwell](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf); the distribution specified is "bernoulli")

Unfortunatly, i find the description in the documentation quite blurry / do not understand it fully:

My core question is: which methods are used, when we plot the variable importance via varImpPlot for random forest and summary for GBM and *are they comparable?*

For the random forest, according to the documentation there are two methods: permuting OOB data and  total decrease in node impurities from splitting on the variable

For the GBM, summary gives out the relative influence. Here the documentation states: "... For other loss functions [in my case bernoulli] this returns the reduction attributable to each variable in sum of squared error in predicting the gradient on each iteration."

Is there a way to consitently compare the variable importance for RF and GBM?

I havent coded anything, this is a rather theoretical question.